# I'm trying to display a single post in Django but I'm getting: Server Error(500)

Tags: python, django, model

I'm using Django to display my post models. When I try to display multiple posts, it works but a single post isn't working for me. I'm not really sure why.
Here is what I did:

> views.py

```
def post(request, pk):
post = Post.object.get(id=pk)

context = {'post': post}
return render(request, 'base/post.html', context)
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name="home"),
path('posts/', views.posts, name='posts'),
path('post/<str:pk>/', views.post, name='post'),]
```

> post.html

```
    <h3>{{post.headline}}</h3>

    <h4>{{post.sub_headline}}</h4>

    <p>{{post.body|linebreaks}}</p>
```

**Edit: More info**

**Post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    # thumbnail =
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True)
    # slug

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

**post.html**

```
    {% extends 'base/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="main-container">
    <img src="{% static 'images/peace.png' %}">
    <h3>{{post.headline}}</h3>

    <h4>{{post.sub_headline}}</h4>

    <p>{{post.body|linebreaks}}</p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**base/main.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Peace Cyebukayire</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Russo+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@500&family=Russo+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/default.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'base/navbar.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <!-- Content goes here -->
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

When I set Debug=True, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/peace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/peace/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/peace/Desktop/Tutorials/Django/my-portfolio/base/views.py", line 24, in post
    post = Post.object.get(id=pk)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /post/1/
Exception Value: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'object'
```

Comment: How does the `Post` model looks like?

Comment: Did you use a base template (template inheritance) in `post.html`?

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem
I added the Post model in the question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Yes I did

Comment: can you share the "base template", and how you made an override for some block?

Comment: Well, am I supposed to change anything in the "base template"?

Comment: you can only override blocks of the base template, if you do not override any block, then the content in the rendered `post.html` will be identical to rendering the base template.

Comment: Cause, it's working for me in the index.html where I'm displaying multiple posts
but when I came to post.html, I had to change only 3 files.
these are: urls.py, views.py and post.html as shown in the question details.

Comment: Please enable [DEBUG mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#debug) in order to obtain a full stack trace.  That will help determine what the actual error is.

Comment: Thanks @Iguananaut
let me do that

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added the base/main.html file in the details

Comment: In your `urls.py` you wrote `path('post/<str:pk>/', views.post, name='post')`, the id is an **integer** but you specify a **string**. Instead try this `path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post, name='post')`

Comment: Typo: `Post.object.get(id = pk)` here `object` should be **`objects`**, i.e. it should be `Post.objects.get(id=pk)`

Comment: @Iguananaut,
I did. Just added the error to question details.
am not really sure what it means.

Exception Value: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'object'

Comment: @Rvector Thanks but I still get the same error

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat, I corrected it.

Comment: @Peace add you posts view template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue no 1**
Your views are very poorly named, there have been problems just like yours before because of the view names. The error sometimes occurs when your view name clashes with your model/your own view/Django's inbuilt functions

**Issue no 2**

```
post = Post.object.get(id=pk) # is WRONG
post = Post.objects.get(id=pk) # OBJECTS is the correct syntax
```

Comment: Wow:)  I thought about this before but just thought that "Post.objects" should only be used for multiple posts.
It worked, Thank you so much @Ruchit Micro